# why nullify instance variables when destroying a stateful EJB?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, javabeans, stateful

In an example of the @remove annotation on a stateful EJB, the annotated method nullifys the bean's instance variables. Why? Surely destroying the bean destroys its contents, i.e. any variables?

Thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 3):

Setting all fields of an object to `null` has two useful effects:

- It provides a hard barrier against logic errors that would lead to an invalid object being reused. The application would crash instead of silently producing incorrect results.
- It helps the Java VM garbage collector by removing edges from the object reference graph, thus improving the overall performance.

Comment: Setting member references to null is [unlikely](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01274/index.html#3.2) to help the garbage collector.

Comment: @McDowell: That would depend on *how* the fields are set to `null`. If it is a simple assignment in the course of normal operation, that is fine and helpful, at least according to my profiler. If it requires replicating the operation of the GC by explicitly walking complex structures, then it's a very bad idea. In general, one should profile their program before going for such micro-optimizations...

Answer (score 2):

Can you post the example source code? Or don't. Pro-actively setting `null` is not needed - when EJB is destroyed and garbage collected soon later, all objects it references (of course providing there are no other references to them) will be garbage collected as well.

Answer (score 0):

If ejbRemove(), Attributes of instance are wiped clean and client still has reference to instance. Client still can access the same object. That is not desirable.